# Corresponding API for CANoeILNLVector.dll file

Tags: canoe

I am using Vector CANoe version 8.5 and I wanted to know what are the APIs for `CANoeILNLVector`.dll file.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the short description of the CANoeILNLVector.dll functions from CAPL browser / Functions window, if the dll is linked to the Simulation node/test node you are editing through CAPL browser.